# Running updatetool in GlassFish 4.0

Tags: java, netbeans, glassfish-4, java-ee-7

I am trying to follow the tutorial **"Your First Cup: An Introduction to the Java EE Platform "**.  However when I try to run the update tool from  both netbeans and the command prompt I get the following error:

```
Installing pkg packages.
Unrecognized exception: no matching package for: pkg-toolkit-incorporation
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: no matching package for: pkg-toolkit-incorporation
        at com.sun.pkg.client.Image.makeInstallPlan(Image.java:1747)
        at com.sun.pkg.client.Image.makeInstallPlan(Image.java:1724)
        at com.sun.pkg.client.Image.installPackages(Image.java:1904)
        at com.sun.pkg.bootstrap.Bootstrap._main(Bootstrap.java:244)
        at com.sun.pkg.bootstrap.Bootstrap._main(Bootstrap.java:163)
        at com.sun.pkg.bootstrap.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:113)

C:\Program Files\glassfish-4.0\bin>
```

I am running this on Windows 8 64 bit however java version is 8u5 64 bit. I am also running Netbeans 8.0

Comment: Are you running the updatetool.exe directly or are you running pkg?